# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout with horizontal or orthogonalScrollingBehavior has inconsistent item spacing near edge of screen

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, diffabledatasource

I have the following layout for my compositional layout

```
func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        (sectionIndex: Int, layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in

        let dayItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(74), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
        // 2. Setup media group
        let dayItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: dayItemSize)
        let dayGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let dayGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: dayGroupSize, subitems: [dayItem])
        let interitemSpacing = CGFloat(10)
        dayGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(interitemSpacing)
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: dayGroup)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
        return section
    }
    return layout
}
```

Then there are 30 "day" items in my collectionView.

```
  fileprivate func makeDataSource() -> DataSource {
        let dataSource = DataSource(
            collectionView: collectionView,
            cellProvider: { (collectionView, indexPath, YearMonthDay) ->
              UICollectionViewCell? in
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: TimelineDayCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? TimelineDayCell
                cell?.configure(with: YearMonthDay)
                cell?.dayLabel.text = String(indexPath.section)+","+String(indexPath.row)
                return cell
            })
        return dataSource
    }
    func configureDataSource() {
        self.collectionView!.register(TimelineDayCell.nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: TimelineDayCell.identifier)
    }
    func applySnapshot(animatingDifferences: Bool = true) {
      // 2
      var snapshot = DataSourceSnapshot()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        snapshot.appendItems(days) # 30 of these
      dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animatingDifferences)
    }
```

My UIcollectionViewController covers the entire width of the screen. My cells in the screen look like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

The text on the cells is their index path. You can see that between 0-4, 5-9 the spacing is uniform, then on the edges 4-5 and 9-10, its different. I believe this is because its the "edge" between screens. But what can I do about it?

I've also tried using no orthogonal scroll behavior and just setting the layout config's scroll direction

```
   let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
   config.scrollDirection = .horizontal
   layout.configuration = config
   return layout
```

It seems to achieve the same thing. Any suggestions here?

EDIT: It seems that this behavior is based on the sizing of the group. For instance when I use let dayGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: dayGroupSize, subitem: dayItem, count: 30), it makes all of the items lie next to each other like so:

[image]

Now there are 30 separate items. Notice how it has auto-spaced the distance between them so that it can fit 30 into 1 screen width. Thus it is still trying to force all of the items in 1 group into a single screen which is the behavior I don't want. I want the group to be the width of the entire content size and to be scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved it. It has to do with the group sizing. I had         `let dayGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))`

The inter-item spacing is between the group items. And the group size was the size of my window. So I need to make the group size the size of the entire content (bigger than the window for instance.

Comment: I realize this comment is years later, but I'm having the same issue and your "solution" here doesn't include how you solved it.  Did you change the line of code above to be .fractionalWidth(2.0) or something like that?

Comment: Yes I changed it to let dayGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(10),heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)). I don't remember how I picked 10 but I guess it is the size of the interItemSpacing. Let me know if this doesn't help and I can dig in more